# how to print all character from file with its position in c?

Tags: c

hello i wrote below a program in c,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    long n=0L;
    fp=fopen("myfile.txt","w");
    printf("Enter the data into file:\n");
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        putc(c,fp);
    }
    printf("Total character into file:%ld\n",ftell(fp));
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("myfile.txt","r");
    while(feof(fp)==0)
    {
        fseek(fp,n,0);
        printf("\n char:'%c' at position '%ld'",getc(fp),ftell(fp));
        n++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    getch();
}
```

it work fine but when i replace the statement:

```
printf("\n char:'%c' at position '%ld'",getc(fp),ftell(fp));
```

with the statement:

```
printf("\n position '%ld'",ftell(fp));
```

**then it will going to infinite loop**
I knew the function,

```
fseek()
```

It set the file pointer to specified position.
but here what happen,i don't understand.
please help me.

Comment: `main()` returns `int`.

Comment: but i use the borland c compiler

Comment: It has nothing to do with the compiler, it's specified by the standard, if borland c compiler which I don't know is not compliant with that use another compiler, `gcc` and `clang` are great.

Comment: And [`while(feof(fp)==0)` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: In second case I guess you get the same position..

Comment: the feof(fp) will return the 0 if file file end no encountred. otherwise it will return the non-zero value.

Comment: Also, please use macros instead of their values, they are macros for a reason `fseek(fp, n, 0);` -> `fseek(fp, n, SEEK_SET);`.

Comment: no i get the different position continuously and my program is going to infinite loop

Comment: dear ihrob , the SEEK_SET  is same as the value 0

Comment: hello i also tried the SEEK_SET, but nothing happen

Comment: Yes it is `0` but it's a macro because if someone ever decided to change it, it will not break your code.

Comment: Why are you trying to `fseek()` `fgetc()` will get one character at a time, and `ftell()` will give you current position in the stream, seeking has a different purpose, can you explain why are you trying that?

Comment: `fseek` does not set the `EOF`.

Comment: i tried to make program, which give me character with its position from file.

Comment: hello BLUEPIX , the `feof() ` will automatically encountered the end of file by `EOF`

Comment: `fseek` clears the terminal state of the file. So `feof()` will not be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for infinite loop : In your second case you do not progress the stream as in first case

[`getc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getc/)

> Returns the character currently pointed by the internal file position indicator of the specified stream. The internal file position indicator is then advanced to the next character.

A solution :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c;

    long n = 0L;
    fp=fopen("main.c","r");

    while(getc(fp)!=EOF)
    {
        fseek(fp,n,0);
        printf("\n position '%ld'",ftell(fp));
        n++ ;
    }
    fclose(fp);

}
```

Furthermore :

`fseek()` do not progress the file pointer.

> Sets the position indicator associated with the stream to a new position.

`feof()`

> This indicator is generally set by a previous operation on the stream
>   that attempted to read at or past the end-of-file."

So this explains your failure. Second implementation does not come across EOF as first case. Provided sample of code would provide you an workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Check in documentation if `fseek` or `ftell` sets `feof()` result. Possibly not, so when you removed `getc` call `feof` can no longer return 'true', hence infinite loop.

Anyway, are you interested in the explanation why **this** program behaves strange or rather how you should write your program properly to achieve the result described...?

Answer (score 0):

`fseek()` will not set the `EOF` marker, and in fact it can unset the `EOF` marker and it should do it after a succesful call.

Also, as the link points out the `while (feof(fp) == 0)` is always wrong, it's because you need to `fgetc()` one extra `char` for the `EOF` marker to be set, so you will have one extra iteration, instead you have to do it this way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE    *fp;
    int      c; /* this should be 'int' and not 'char' */
    long int n;

    fp = fopen("myfile.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return -1;
    printf("Enter the data into file:\n");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putc(c, fp);
    printf("Total character into file:%ld\n", ftell(fp));
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen("myfile.txt","r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return -1;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
            printf("charcater `\\n' at position '%ld'\n", ftell(fp));
        else
            printf("charcater `%c' at position '%ld'\n", c, ftell(fp));
        n++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A successful call `fseek` function clear the end-of-file indicator, but your loop condition rely on `feof`, so `feof(fp) == 0` always true.

Answer (score 0):

fseek(SEEK_SET) merely sets the FILE's pointer to a position in the file.  It doesn't actually do any reading of the file or anything.  So, it will gladly let you set the position to WAY past the end of the file (and it clears any existing EOF set on the stream).  ftell() merely returns the position of the file pointer.

Without doing a read of some sort (e.g. - getc()), EOF won't be set on the stream and your loop will be infinite.

You can do a fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) and then an ftell() to know the size / end of the file position.

PS - You really need to check your return values more carefully and handle any failures.